# chardet2 (?) issue when installing dotcloud on an Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, pip, dotcloud

I just signed up for DotCloud and got this while installing the pip package. Tried to fiddle around and could not solve it.
Running pip 1.2.1 under python 3.2.

Sorry, I don't know bits of Python so could not really figure out how to solve this by myself. If you have any python help to give me, please do it gently (although I do know PHP/Ruby pretty well).

```
$ sudo easy_install pip && sudo pip install dotcloud
[sudo] password for myself: 
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.2.1
pip 1.2.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip-3.2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
Downloading/unpacking dotcloud
Running setup.py egg_info for package dotcloud

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argparse in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages (from dotcloud)
Downloading/unpacking requests==0.14.2 (from dotcloud)
Running setup.py egg_info for package requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-build/requests/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
import requests
File "requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
from . import utils
File "requests/utils.py", line 22, in <module>
from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
File "requests/compat.py", line 112, in <module>
from .packages import chardet2 as chardet
ImportError: cannot import name chardet2
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build/requests/setup.py", line 6, in <module>

import requests

File "requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>

from . import utils

File "requests/utils.py", line 22, in <module>

from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header

File "requests/compat.py", line 112, in <module>

from .packages import chardet2 as chardet

ImportError: cannot import name chardet2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, for now DotCloud does not support Python 3, which unfortunately is the default version for Python on newer machines.

Thus, looks like it's not possible to install dotcloud through pip.
However, I managed to download the [standalone package](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/dotcloud/dotcloud-0.9.4.tar.gz#md5=1f2caf78f8f1bf4c441d18cbfe3d6ce8), unpacked it and installed using `sudo ./setup.py install`. The script calls for Python 2.7 automatically and installs everything cleanly.

Comment: the dotCloud platform supports Python 3, but the CLI does not. If you'd like to add Python 3 support, please fork [the github repo](https://github.com/dotcloud/dotcloud-cli) and make a pull request when you have a working version.

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to requests and python 3.2.  Could you try installing the following packages and then retry installing the dotCloud CLI?

```
pip install chardet2 urllib3
```

[Need help installing requests for python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994337/need-help-installing-requests-for-python-3)

Comment: I already had tried `pip install chardet2`. This command only installed urllib3, and the problem persists... The same error about chardet2 appears if I try to `pip install requests`.

Comment: It looks like there's an open bug within requests to fix this issue.  Here are some of the related issue topics: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/916  https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/939  https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/951

Comment: hmmm thanks! However, the issues seem to be closed. Would I be able to install an older or development version where the issue does not exist/is closed?

Comment: as it seems, there's no support for python 3 on the dotcloud CLI client yet. This should be pointed in the documentation, so there's no need for googling trying to understand why the install command does not work - python 3 is default in many ubuntu boxes now.