# Why is is this "Invalid syntax" in Python?

Tags: python

This isn't my code, it is a module I found on the internet which performs (or is supposed to perform) the task I want.

```
print  '{'
for page in range (1,4):
    rand = random.random()
    id = str(long( rand*1000000000000000000 ))
    query_params = { 'q':'a',
        'include_entities':'true', 'lang':'en',
         'show_user':'true',
         'rpp': '100', 'page': page,
         'result_type': 'mixed',
         'max_id':id}
    r = requests.get('http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
                 params=query_params)
    tweets = json.loads(r.text)['results']
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.get('text') :
            print  tweet
print  '}'
print
```

The Python shell seems to indicate that the error is one Line 1. I know very little Python so have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? If >= 3.0 use `print()` (it is now a function)

Comment: That sorted.. that bit. Now I'm getting "ImportError: No module named 'requests'"

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994337/need-help-installing-requests-for-python-3), looks like it may solve your problem with `requests` module.

Comment: @user1765369: You probably don't have a module named `request` installed, but please: one question per post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet is written for Python 2.x, but in Python 3.x (where `print` is now a proper function). Replace `print SomeExp` with `print(SomeExpr)` to solve this.

Here's a [detailed description](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) of this difference (along with other changes in 3.x).