# How to prevent LXML error 'failed to load external entity'

Tags: python, html, linux, parsing, lxml

I'm having some trouble with `lxml.html.parse()`:

Here's my code (shortened):

```
import lxml.html

class Scraper:

    def fetch(self, url):

        tree = None

        try:
            parser = lxml.html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf8')
            tree = lxml.html.parse(url, parser)
        except IOError as e:
            print('ERROR LOADING PAGE: ' + str(e))

        return tree
```

It mostly works fine, but sometimes I'm getting a lot of those errors:

> ERROR LOADING PAGE: Error reading file
>   'b'http://twitter.com/wordpressdotcom'': b'failed to load external
>   entity "http://twitter.com/wordpressdotcom"'
>
> ERROR LOADING PAGE: Error reading file
>   'b'http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0375714634/ref=la_B001IGSNMM_1_9_cp_1_pap_olp/185-7720102-5178158?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1391249475&sr=1-9&condition=collectible'':
>   b'failed to load HTTP resource'
>
> ERROR LOADING PAGE: Error reading file
>   'b'http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/559098'': b'failed to
>   load external entity
>   "http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/559098"'

I've looked into other questions and answers here, but all they can suggest is using urllib - but that didn't really help when I tried it.

What I want is to **disable loading "external entities"**, whatever the hell it means. All I want is the html at the given URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I sniff with Wireshark I see this:

For `http://twitter.com/wordpressdotcom`:

```
GET /wordpressdotcom HTTP/1.0
Host: twitter.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip

HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
content-length: 0
date: Sat, 01 Feb 2014 12:08:01 UTC
location: https://twitter.com/wordpressdotcom
server: tfe
set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A139125648190241848; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 01-Feb-2016 12:08:01 UTC
```

For `http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0375714634/ref=la_B001IGSNMM_1_9_cp_1_pap_olp/185-7720102-5178158?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1391249475&sr=1-9&condition=collectible`

```
GET /gp/offer-listing/0375714634/ref=la_B001IGSNMM_1_9_cp_1_pap_olp/185-7720102-5178158?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1391249475&sr=1-9&condition=collectible HTTP/1.0
Host: www.amazon.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Date: Sat, 01 Feb 2014 12:10:49 GMT
Server: Server
Last-Modified: Fri, 30 Nov 2012 01:26:22 GMT
ETag: "3dd-4cfac498acb80-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 599
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

...........SMo.0...Wp..]b....M...Pl.....`l.V+K..8M..(;.v.a..S..(.=.m....l.k.u......~...V....b.....j:.U...S.u."..k.|vy....J.P4..fY...x0..7....[Kp....S.Y.O...>B.GKk.c].....0/..wR9.ag.q...F...6hg....M....d........N.vk..Yi}8.r.......V..t
.... !...B.0..f.._9.G...\....OY0...-..{........xZ^.......n~.(8.:.k%1
Z2M+....[.5.Z.2.R..DL.KV.y2.Y...4N...z....Z.N....V........].DV.z^..}..j>W.;..WB.bS.......ba.3.g..G8......".}b...th1....a."`x........>[.@......8-........z.q.{.CJE.@>.d..?...UK...dQ'.J
....KW..v...iK.q.=-AI.?....za7.=/u/.......T.Sf}...\t.iJ. ..8.....U...dg...9..t#.g......Lz.. .?...i.........L]....
```

And for `http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/559098`

```
GET /changeset/559098 HTTP/1.0
Host: plugins.trac.wordpress.org
Accept-Encoding: gzip

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 01 Feb 2014 12:13:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/559098
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 242
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

..........uO.N.0...+L..eh..L$X;1i@......fR.DI:...n.r.l?.....|.4.u./.......n..-..j..eS^..(...\fd..K2.t..1.,...l.4j.."#<.....3.N^..e.dc..m....F....5.....171......;.AD.Z.c.v.C..w..5v.8.r....\..L.. t..OEi=3..Sm.<.?.....e....*................|7...
```

`lxml` apparently doesnt handle redirections, and for the Amazon case you probably need to use a real "User-Agent" header.

You should use another library to download the content of the page, e.g. [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or [`urllib(2)`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml), and then feed this HTML to `lxml.html`

Comment: Okay, I think I'll look into `requests`. But this isn't a real solution, I just wanted to disable external entity loading.

Comment: Well you can still instantiate the parser with `no_network=True` (see http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.HTMLParser-class.html) but I don't think it will help here, since the start page fails to load (it's the external entity that could not be loaded), not linked external entities... Oh `not_network=True` is already the default

Comment: Any idea if `requests` exists for python3? From the projects page it looks like it does, `pip install requests` worked, but I can't import it.

Comment: Check these: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/faq/#python-3-support , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994337/need-help-installing-requests-for-python-3

Comment: I got it working with urllib in the end, so I guess I can close this