# ImportError: No module named 'requests' Python 3.4.0

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-requests

When attempting to import the requests module in Python 3.4.0 I receive the following error:  `ImportError: No module named 'requests'`

The `requests` module in previous version of Python required that you use `pip` separately. But according to the new features in Python 3.4.0, `pip` is built in: https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-453

My import line is simply:

```
import requests
```

I am confused as to why this is not working. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You still need to *use* pip to install `requests`, you just no longer have to install `pip`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having `pip` included is meant to ease retrieving new packages. It does not state that all modules reachable through pip are bundled in new Python (hopefully !).

You are still required to `pip install requests` before using the package `requests`.

**Edit:** following [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994337/need-help-installing-requests-for-python-3), it seems dependencies on requests are flawed. Then try:

```
pip install chardet2 urllib3
```

as suggested by mentioned SO question.

Comment: @Richard: Updated with new info. Let us try if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 8):

There is a possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322792).

1. Install `pip` for python 3: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
2. Use `pip3` to install request module: `pip3 install requests`

If you get permission denied error, run the previous command in sudoers mode: `sudo pip3 install requests`

Answer (score 1):

Although `pip` is built-in, you still have to call `pip install requests`. `pip` is just the tool for downloading, not the actual item. To download, use the following:

```
bash-3.2$ pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Downloading requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (625kB): 625kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: requests
Cleaning up...
...
```

You don't have to install `pip`, but you still have to use it to install other items.

Answering your comment, run the `pip install` again, this time with a `sudo`. You should see the following message:

```
$ sudo pip install requests
Password:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
```

Or something of the likes. Then run this:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests
<module 'requests' from '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

If the `import` fails, go to the above directory and search for the files.

Comment: Even after doing 'pip install requests', it still returns the same error. Do I have to change any PATH variables to make sure Python knows where to look for the installed modules?

Comment: This did not work with Python 3.4.0, but I just installed Python 2.7.6 and the requests library can be imported. Any way to put get the requests library specifically for '/Library/Python/3.4/'?

Comment: instead of pip install one needs to do `pip3 install`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I solved it by installing `requests` in the app's virtual environment instead of global Python environment. The commands are:

```
python3 -m venv tutorial-env
tutorial-env\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install request
```