# "ImportError: no module named 'requests'" after installing with pip

Tags: python, pip, importerror

I am getting `ImportError : no module named 'requests'`.

But I have installed the `requests` package using the command `pip install requests`.

On running the command `pip freeze` in the command prompt, the result is

```
requests==2.7.0
```

So why is this sort of error happening while running the python file?

Comment: What does `pip -V` and `python -V` show?

Comment: There are numbers of reasons for such behaviour. Most likely you have multiple versions of Python installed.

Comment: Ya....you were right I think in my python 3.4 versions pip is not installed.

Comment: Adding to Alik's comment: Had a similar problem and it turns out that had 2 separate pythonx.x binaries installed in different locations (/usr/bin/pythonx.x and /bin/pythonx.x) and when installing with pip, was installing for /bin/pythonx.x and `which pythonx.x` would show /bin/pythonx.x (had to change interpreter (since was using PyCharm)).

Answer (score 13):

Run in command prompt.

```
pip list
```

Check what version you have installed on your system if you have an old version.

Try to uninstall the package...

```
pip uninstall requests
```

Try after to install it:

```
pip install requests
```

You can also test if pip does not do the job.

```
easy_install requests
```

Comment: From pip install requests command it is installing requests module in python 2 version.  But, I want to install requests module in python 3.4 version. How should I do that???

Comment: I think you can find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283045/importerror-no-module-named-requests-python-3-4-0

Comment: That is the equivalent to "Have you tried turning it off and on again?". Not nice.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error before when I was executing a python3 script, after this:

`sudo pip3 install requests`

the problem solved, If you are using python3, give a shot.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason is that you have multiple python executables in your environment, for example 2.6.x, 2.7.x or virtaulenv. You might install the package into one of them and run your script with another.

Type python in the prompt, and press the tab key to see what versions of Python in your environment.

Comment: I have python 2.7 and python 3.4 versions installed. pip command is not working when I am running my script with python 3.4 version.

Comment: Try to install packages by pip3.

Comment: pip3 is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file...........is coming when I have used the command pip3 install requests

Answer (score 1):

In Windows it worked for me only after trying the following:
1. Open cmd inside the folder where "requests" is unpacked. (CTRL+SHIFT+right mouse click, choose the appropriate popup menu item)
2. (Here is the path to your pip3.exe)\pip3.exe install requests
Done

Answer (score 0):

if it works when you do :

```
python
>>> import requests
```

then it might be a mismatch between a previous version of python on your computer and the one you are trying to use

in that case : check the location of your working python:

`which python`
And get sure  it is matching the first line in your python code

```
#!<path_from_which_python_command>
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening CMD in the location of the already installed request folder and running "pip install requests" worked for me. I am using two different versions of Python.

I think this works because requests is now installed outside my virtual environment. Haven't checked but just thought I'd write this in, in case anyone else is going crazy searching on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
pip show <module name>
```

and check the module causing issue, is in which location, this will tell you which Python installation you should use as your interpreter or else you can copy the module files manually to your current Python interpreter installation's location.

[image]