# Python Package not found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a virtual environment and installed all required packages and running the python code. all looks okay and not seen any issue. Later I have a requirement to connect to an api and get data. For this, I have installed requests==2.22.0 in the virtual environment and running the python code but end up with No module named "requests".

Could you please advise me what went wrong in this case to import the requests module into my code I appreciate you quick help.

Thanks,
Bhaskar.

Comment: Do `pip freeze` inside the virtual environment to see if package is installed or not.

Comment: try using an older version of the library..

Comment: @Bhaskar How did you install these packages ? `venv/bin/pip install requests` ? or just `pip install requests` without activating the `environment` ?

Comment: try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069002/python-request-module-not-working

Comment: you either installed `requests` elsewhere (not in the respective virtual environment) or using different python installation than the one you think (e.g. system one, not the virtual environment)  and `requests` is the first package it cannot find

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have python 2.6 and python 2.7. how to point python 2.7. please advise