# ImportError: No module named 'requests' .. despite installing does not show up on Vagrant

Tags: python, vagrant, pip, importerror

I using a Windows 10 machine running a flask web application via a python file on Vagrant (Ubuntu) via putty(SSH).

I get the following error -  ImportError: no module named 'requests'- everytime I try to run my python file despite that fact that I have installed the package via `pip`

On running the command pip freeze in the command prompt, the result is
`requests==2.16.5`

However `pip list` does not return `requests` on Vagrant. On which I am running this python file.

Note: I read this post but it's solutions didn't seem to work for me (reinstalling after deleting `requests` )- ["ImportError: no module named 'requests'" after installing with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535384/importerror-no-module-named-requests-after-installing-with-pip)

[image: python import error]

*python -V*
[image: Python version]

*`pip list` on Vagrant*
[image: pip list on Vangrant]

Comment: `which pip;which python` <- give output

Comment: pip 9.0.1 and python 2.7 I believe .. I have attached screenshots of my result now.

Comment: no I dont need versions, `which` shows path