# No module named 'requests' Python 3.5.0

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I need to use ***requests*** in my code but it says that it's not installed. I get the following error: `No module named 'requests'`. It's actually installed and works in python 2.7: `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. I searched a lot and tried to reinstall it, to [download missing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994337/need-help-installing-requests-for-python-3), and etc... but nothing helped. How can I make it work on python 3.5 ?

Comment: did you actually tried to import it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python 2 and 3 (and their packages) can be installed and co-exist independently of one another. I would suggest using `pip` as the best way to install Python packages (and keep them up-to-date).

1. Install `pip` for Python 3 – using one of the following methods:

   - `easy_install` (may be available as `easy_install-3.5`),
   - the distribution package manager (if running GNU/Linux) or
   - `python -m ensurepip` (thanks, Mark Dickinson)
2. Use `pip` to install the `requests` module:

   ```
   pip3 install requests
   ```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the use of `python -m ensurepip` to install `pip`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks. I didn't know you could do that. With GNU/Linux distributions I've always installed pip using the distro package manager and with Cygwin, I used `easy_install` to install pip itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can even place the "requests" Folder (https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tree/master/requests) next to your "script.py" and import requests from any script within the folder containing the requests folder
    `> root
    --> requests
    ----> init.py
    ----> [more]
    --> script.py`

script.py can now import requests as always

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and shortest answer would just be to do

```
pip install requests
```

And if you encounter a error try doing

```
sudo pip install requests
```

More info on this module can be found here
https://pypi.org/project/requests/