# Python 3 Install Requests Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, command-line, pip, python-requests

Can you please assist. I am trying to install the requests module on Windows 10. I have Python 3.6 except I get this error:

```
Exception:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
            status = self.run(options, args)
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
            prefix=options.prefix_path,
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
            **kwargs
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
            self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
            isolated=self.isolated,
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
            clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
            ensure_dir(destdir)
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
            os.makedirs(path)
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
            mkdir(name, mode)
        PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\certifi'

        C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6>
```

I have tried this also: [Need help installing requests for python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994337/need-help-installing-requests-for-python-3)

except I now get this error:

```
        error: could not create 'C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\chardet': Access is denied

        ----------------------------------------
    Command ""C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKIT~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-8_kn19l3\\chardet2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NICKIT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-77kpa8t5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NICKIT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-8_kn19l3\chardet2\
```

Anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Are you logged as the Administrator? It just seems like you don't have privileges to create new folders.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's really weird...I am the administrator of this PC. Would it help if I ran CMD as administrator?

Comment: It's worth trying for sure.

Comment: It actually worked! I typed in the py -m pip install requests and it installed the module. Thanks for your help.